# Using zoo package I got a odd frequency

Tags: r, time-series, frequency

I used a zoo object in order to make a Time series. I have a value by hour along several years in my datasets

> Seriet<-read.zoo(df_workload_cpu, index = 1:2, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H",tz="UTC",regular=TRUE)

Afterwards I converted my zoo object in a new xts object

> Seriet.xts <- as.xts(Seriet)

and when I used periodicity function I get this value

> periodicity(Seriet.xts)

Hourly periodicity from 2015-01-01 to 2018-06-30 23:00:0

This information is expected by me...

> str(Seriet.xts)

An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-01/2018-06-30 23:00:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:30648, 1] 992 965 1012 1125 1086 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:
 NULL

> head (Seriet.xts)

```
                [,1]
```

2015-01-01 00:00:00  992
2015-01-01 01:00:00  965
2015-01-01 02:00:00 1012
2015-01-01 03:00:00 1125
2015-01-01 04:00:00 1086
2015-01-01 05:00:00  978

But when I used the frequency function I get the following result:

> frequency(Seriet)
>   [1] 0.0002777778

I was reading different articles according this issue and I don´t kwnow how interpret this result, because the frequency wasn´t put by me when I made the object, I only used the index parameter in the function read.zoo, then how interpret this value?.

If I used the decompose function wiht this object I get this message:

> plot(decompose(Seriet.xts))

Error in decompose(as.ts(Seriet.xts)) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods

I got the same result using a ts object.
¿is possible change the frequency in order to use the decompose function?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What programming language is this?  R?  You need to tag your question with the name of the programming language you're using.

Comment: I´m sorry. with r..

Comment: Note that 1/0.0002777778 = 3600

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It´s true I didn´t realize in this sense... Then, I must suppose that I have 1 value every 3600 possible (60 minutos * 60 seconds). Is this the meaning of my frequency?.

Comment: If I have a value every hour, then the only possible frequency value is 1/3600 or is possible manipule the idea of frequency ?. Why I can´t use the decompose function with this value of frequency?